# (x, 0) in the negative half space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, regression

My course textbook writes this about weight spaces when talking about linear classification:
[image].

Why would $w^{T}x$ be considered to be in the negative half space if $0$ is not less than $0$?

Edit: for further clarification, I'm confused as to the line " similarly, the set of weight vectors...this is also a half space" because it seems the case $(x,0)$ is classified in the negative half space because of the logic that $w^Tx<0$, which by the given label - $0$ - is not less than $0$.

Edit 2: Here are the [slides](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ergrosse/courses/csc311_f20/slides/lec03.pdf) talking about half spaces

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking here. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: edited please check again.

Comment: One is an open halfspace and the other is a closed halfspace. The negative training halfspace is open. Sketch the two and three dimensional cases to see what's going on.

Comment: Why is the negative half space open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each weight vector $w$ defines a (linear) classifier $f_w$ by
$$f_w(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } w^T x \geq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise, i.e. } w^T x < 0
\end{cases}$$
You are confusing $w^T x$ with $f_w(x)$, presumably because the book conflates the weight vector $w$ and the associated classifier $f_w$.

Comment: But isn't the label of (x,0) still 0? So wouldn't it have to be the second case anyways?

Comment: You are still conflating $w^T x$ and the label. They are not the same, and they are not meant to be either -- $w^T x$ is just a value from which the label is derived.

Comment: What would $f_w(x)$ be? Would it be the output from specific training sample? And how does it put it then in the negative half space? Thanks for your replies btw

Comment: $f_w(x)$ is the label assigned to the data point $x$ using the weight vector $w$. The complete process to get to that label is (1) computing $w^T x$ and then (2) checking whether or not $w^T x$ is less than zero or greater (or equal) to zero. In the former case we assign the label 0, in the latter one we assign the label 1. Note again that $w^T x$ is just some real number, not the label.

Comment: We can associate with each label $\ell$ the set of points such that the label assigned by our process is $\ell$.
In the case of a binary linear classifier we basically have a hyperplane (defined by $w$) running through our $n$-dimensional vector space of inputs splitting the space into two _half spaces_, One of these half spaces is the set of inputs such that $w^T x < 0$ (we label those 0) and the other half space is the set of inputs such that $w^T x \geq 0$ (we label these 1).

Comment: Oh right, it's the prediction by the "trained" model.

Comment: So the snippet from the text is just defining (x,0) to be in the negative half space?

Comment: So I guess whenever you say "negative half space" you mean the half space defined by $w^T x < 0$. If that is a definition I cannot tell from the language, depends on what is said in the paragraphs before the one you provided.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the relevant slide

Comment: In that case, I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: Ah ok. So to recap, the half spaces are those that contain predictions (along with their corresponding predictors) which belong so some class or another. The labels are those that assign them to some class? And we split based on what labels these predictions belong to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113729/discussion-between-watercrystal-and-user2793618).